Nestjs Request Timeout with MongoDB
I have a setup where nestjs is hosted in ECS Fargate, my service randomly starts to timeout and its only with API's which interact with MongoDB, all other api's seem to be working as expected. a redeployment of the Service fixes it immediately until it randomly happens again. I am not using any DB.createSession in my code, using nest's inbuilt Singelton Module, I have a M10 cluster which I guess has a limit of 100 connection.
Here is the options on connection string:
maxPoolSize=15&minPoolSize=1&connectTimeoutMS=30000&socketTimeoutMS=30000

    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const uri: string | undefined = configService.get(
          EnvironmentKeyName.MONGODB_USER_URI
        );
        return {
          uri,
        } as MongooseModuleOptions;
      },
    }),

And using forFeature in individual Modules.
My current health API doesn't hit the DB, I am sure if I add a DB call which fails it will restart the service. Is there a proper fix to this??
